# Can Temporal Property query be optimized to remove a MAX subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following DDL which is attempting to implement the [Temporal Property pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/TemporalProperty.html)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `effective_on` DATE NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `superceded_by` int(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create unique index zzz on `docs` (id);
alter table `docs` add FOREIGN KEY (superceded_by) REFERENCES docs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX xyz ON `docs` (name, effective_on, superceded_by);
```

and corresponding query

```
select `value` from docs
where
superceded_by is null and name = 'p1' and
effective_on = (
select max(effective_on) from docs
where
superceded_by is null
and effective_on <= '2017-01-01'
and name = 'p1' )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a07c84/1

The current SQL uses a sub-query which I was wondering if it can be eliminated or have the query further simplified for performance.

Answer (score 0):

for performance  you should add   a composite index  on

```
table docs  columns (effective_on, name, superceded_by )
```

you unique index on id is unsufeul you have already a primary key index on id

and also the constrain for Foreign key on the table itself have not sense

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query like this:

```
select d.`value`
from docs d
where d.superceded_by is null and
      d.name = 'p1' and
      d.effective_on = (select max(d2.effective_on)
                        from docs d2
                        where d2.superceded_by is null and
                              d2.name = d.name and
                              d2.effective_on <= '2017-01-01'
                       );
```

Then you want an index on `docs(name, superceded_by, effective_on)`.  The order of the columns in the index is quite important.  The first key is used for the correlation clause; the second for filtering by `superceded_by`.  The final key should then be scanned to get the right date.